# Why does xterm alt-backspace produce the Unicode character U+00FF?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xterm

In xterm, when I press `alt-backspace`, xterm produces the Unicode character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS' (U+00FF) as described [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff/index.htm). It shows up on-screen as a 'y' character with two dots above it.

What component, code or configuration causes this particular Unicode sequence to be emitted when alt-backspace is typed? terminfo? Is it hard-coded in xterm? Xkb? Something else?

I'd appreciation any pointers to configuration files, man pages, source code, and so forth. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You wanted a man page?

`man xterm`

```
   eightBitInput (class EightBitInput)
           If  “true”,  Meta  characters (a single-byte character combined
           with the Meta modifier key) input from the  keyboard  are  pre‐
           sented  as a single character, modified according to the eight‐
           BitMeta resource.  If “false”, Meta  characters  are  converted
           into  a  two-character  sequence with the character itself pre‐
           ceded by ESC.  The default is “true”.
```

No applause or thank you necessary: Just click the sad little grey check-mark till it turns green.  For any future questions: [just click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).  **;-)**

Comment: how do I start `xterm` with `eightBitInput` set to false ?

Comment: You have to put it in the config file: http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm

Answer (score 4):

put arrow in middle of term then keep pushed Ctrl+left mouse button and in menu check option "Meta send escape"

edit file  /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm
add this line at the end

*metaSendsEscape: True